# Xamarin.iOS SQLite errors cause drive to crash but runs perfectly on simulator

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

So we are building an iOS only application that uses SQLite to store data locally.  I have been running this on the iOS simulator and it has run perfectly but when I run it on a physical iPad (same OS version as the simulator) there are a large number of errors that are output.

First, I get an error while trying to create table (again, this error doesn't appear on the simulator and it creates the table just fine in the simulator) As you can see below, it doesn't create the "query" correctly as it doesn't add any of the attributes, which are all public members of the class:
[image]

One exception that is thrown is that there is "Get Method not found for 'phoneNumber' ".  In the class definition for this class every attribute is public and has {get; set;} defined.  If the phoneNumber attribute is commented out, this error is thrown on the next attribute in the class saying that it can't find that one.
[image]

[image]

Also, when debugging it seems that the public members of the class are private when debugging on the device (which may be the cause of the above error).  See the below images, the first is when debugging on the simulator, the second is debugging on the physical iPad:
[image]

[image]

Has anyone else had so many issues with the SQLite library on physical devices?  Any advise would help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, in case anyone else looks here I was able to figure out my issue. Because the class that I used to create the table wasn't being referenced anywhere in my code yet (it was a new table that I had just added), the compiler was stripping it's definition from my code and so that when Sqlite went to create it it didn't find anything and hence the errors. Similarly for the attributes, I didn't have a reference to all of them in my code so it was stripping them out.

This line at the top of each class used to create a sqlite table fixes that, it tells the compiler to keep all parts of the class:

```
[Foundation.Preserve( AllMembers = true ) ]
public class School
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id{ get; set;}
    public string schoolName{ get; set;}
    public string schoolAcronym{ get; set;}
    public string schoolState{ get; set; }
}
```